# Failing to setup VS Code with MingW-64; can't get simple HelloWorld.cpp to work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I have so far failed to get VS Code to compile a simple helloworld.cpp file with MingW-64 (v8.1.0). I'm doing this on windows 10 for the first time, and have had issues at pretty much every stage of trying to get MingW-64 to work with VS Code in one way or another, following this tutorial roughly: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

I have setup my environment variables to include the path to mingw64, and can see the version numbers in terminal, no issue.

When I run my code, the terminal shows that my build finished successfully, debug returns "ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139." and the output window just shows that it ran the .exe and .cpp file and completed. I can't see that it has printed to terminal at all.

Extensions;
C/C++,
code runner,
ESLint,
npm

HelloWorld.cpp;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
   {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "C:\\mingw64\\bin",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "a.exe",
                "HelloWorld.cpp"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Make certain you can compile and debug with the tools from the command line.

Comment: 0xc0000139 is a failure to find a DLL. what happens when you try to run the built program from a console window?

Comment: Why VSCode? Just curious, because to me it seems there are good alternatives for Windows developers.

Comment: `code runner` I believe will not use your `tasks.json`

Comment: Definitely missed something on my part because the program runs fine from console! I was keen to use VS Code as I have always used it as an editor but not to compile or debug, but please feel free to suggest a good IDE for windows; I'm in the process of choosing between VSCode, Visual Studio 2022 and Codelite

Comment: My vote is for Visual Studio Community 2022